# How to split an application so multiple developers can work on it together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**Background**

There are a lot of good resources on how to use MVVM/MVP to separate your layers so that the designer and coder can work separately. This isn't a PRISM question, but I have also checked several Prism tutorials ( including [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPoBurR0JnM)  excellent 4+ hours series by Microsoft' Mike Taulty, and many more)

These tutorials/books/videos explain the internal workings, such as how to pass messages across view models, how to modularize the application, the best security practices and so on.

**However, no one talks about how to actually **logically divide**an application (WPF or ASP.Net MVC) so that multiple people can work on it.**

**Question**

How do you generally go about assigning responsibilities to your development team?

Assuming that you use a high level UML tool, once a high level diagram is ready but no code has been written, how do you ensure that

1- The developer(s) working on the UI will know and be able to access the class library functions that the class-library developers **will** write?

2- Two libraries that will be written for two different purposes by two different developers will inter operate?

I hope I am not being confusing here. The question is just for a few good rules of thumb. That as two people working on two projects ( WPF/Silverlight or ASP.Net MVC) in a solution will take two different ways , how do the methods/classes/functions written by one fit together with the others?

Thank you

Comment: Could be better in [programmers.se]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand of your question(s), you want to have an infrastructure in your project that people with different skills can work separately. If I were right, "Domain Driven Design" would be the best infrastructure you can choose.

Domain-driven design (DDD) is an approach to develop software for complex needs by connecting the implementation to an evolving model. The premise of domain-driven design is the following:

1. Placing the project's primary focus on the core domain and domain logic.
2. Basing complex designs on a model of the domain.
3. Initiating a creative collaboration between technical and domain experts to iteratively refine a conceptual model that addresses particular domain problems.

The term was coined by Eric Evans in his book of the same title.

There is a great project that can help you: [Microsoft Spain - Domain Oriented N-Layered .NET 4.0 Sample App](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com) is based on simple scenarios easy to understand which is well documented.

Concepts like modularity, layering, etc. are discussed in the project very carefully which I believe can fulfill your expectation.

Obviously, you need a source control like Team Foundation Server or other alternatives that provide control over changes to source code among multiple developers.

Comment: Super! +1 for the link , I was looking for a decent sized projects with this kind of documentation! A+++++++++

Answer (score 2):

> However, no one talks about how to actually *logically divide*an application (WPF or ASP.Net MVC) so that multiple people can work on it.

You don't really need to divide an application so that multiple people can work on it: you can also use a [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server). There's also a free version available for 5 users or fewer.

[Tutorial: Getting Started with TFS in VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2009/10/21/tutorial-getting-started-with-tfs-in-vs2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> That as two people working on two projects ( WPF/Silverlight or
>   ASP.Net MVC) in a solution will take two different ways , how do the
>   methods/classes/functions written by one fit together with the others?

You need maintain some common library for public functions. And the two developers need to make code review every 2 or 3 weeks. So they could find their difference and learn from each others.